# Oracle - Way to rewrite this query to not use sub-selects?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to create a materialized view in Oracle 11.1, which apparently does not support nested selects in a materialized view (Why this is, I haven't been able to figure out)..  Is there a way to write this query to work as a materialized view?  Thanks!

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_Area90DayReport
  NOLOGGING
  CACHE
  BUILD IMMEDIATE 
  REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT 
  AS 
    select
      T.TASKID,
      V.PROJECTID,
      V.VERSIONID,
      T.GOLDDATE,
      P.BUSINESSLAUNCHDATE,
      V.NAME as ProjectName,
      T.NAME as TaskName,
      T.COURSECODE,
      DT.NAME as DeliveryMethod,
      T.DELIVERABLELENGTHHOUR,
      T.DELIVERABLELENGTHMINUTE,
      V.PRIORITY,
      (SELECT MIN(STARTDATE) FROM TPM_TRAININGPLAN WHERE PROJECTID=V.PROJECTID AND TRAININGPLANTYPE='prescribed') as TrainingDeliveryDate,
      (SELECT wm_concat(WORKGROUPID) FROM TPM_PROJECTWORKGROUPS WHERE PROJECTID=V.PROJECTID GROUP BY PROJECTID) as Workgroups,
    from TPM_TASK T
    inner join TPM_PROJECTVERSION V ON (V.PROJECTID = T.PROJECTID AND V.VERSIONID = T.VERSIONID)
    inner join TPM_PROJECT P ON (P.PROJECTID = T.PROJECTID)
    inner join TPM_DOCUMENTTYPE DT ON (DT.DOCUMENTTYPEID = T.DOCUMENTTYPEID);
```

The error I get is:

```
>[Error] Script lines: 1-25 -------------------------
 ORA-22818: subquery expressions not allowed here
 Script line 20, statement line 20, column 115
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
select
  T.TASKID,
  V.PROJECTID,
  V.VERSIONID,
  T.GOLDDATE,
  P.BUSINESSLAUNCHDATE,
  V.NAME as ProjectName,
  T.NAME as TaskName,
  T.COURSECODE,
  DT.NAME as DeliveryMethod,
  T.DELIVERABLELENGTHHOUR,
  T.DELIVERABLELENGTHMINUTE,
  V.PRIORITY,
  TP.TrainingDeliveryDate,
  WG.Workgroups,
from TPM_TASK T
inner join TPM_PROJECTVERSION V ON (V.PROJECTID = T.PROJECTID AND V.VERSIONID = T.VERSIONID)
inner join TPM_PROJECT P ON (P.PROJECTID = T.PROJECTID)
inner join TPM_DOCUMENTTYPE DT ON (DT.DOCUMENTTYPEID = T.DOCUMENTTYPEID)
left join (
  SELECT PROJECTID, MIN(STARTDATE) as TrainingDeliveryDate
  FROM TPM_TRAININGPLAN
  WHERE TRAININGPLANTYPE='prescribed'
  GROUP BY PROJECTID
) TP on TP.PROJECTID=V.PROJECTID
left join (
  SELECT PROJECTID, wm_concat(WORKGROUPID) as Workgroups
  FROM TPM_PROJECTWORKGROUPS
  GROUP BY PROJECTID
) WG on WG.PROJECTID=V.PROJECTID
```

Comment: That query works, but it's quite slow.  It's about 6 seconds, rather than 0.5sec of my query.  However, maybe for a materialized view it doesn't matter if FAST UPDATE is enabled..  I haven't tried making a MV out of it yet though.

Comment: Doh!  I might have misspoke.  The query window I was running my query in was set to limit to 50 rows.  I created a new query window and ran your query, and it had no row limit.  Our queries are actually around the same speed.

Comment: So now I get the error: ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view

Comment: It seems that FAST REFRESH won't work with GROUP BY in inline views and won't work with WM_CONCAT (see the document linked in Saket's answer).

Comment: Yea, and ON COMMIT won't work with it either.  I ended up creating a REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND view and that works.  However, selecting from it seems to take as long as just running the query to begin with - so now I'm wondering if there's any point to making this an MV, if it's just as slow I might as well just make it a view..  Sigh.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a limitation (that was raised as a bug sometime back), documented here on the Oracle site - http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10736/basicmv.htm#sthref431

To resolve, you should use JOINS rather than subqueries.